# Import Error: cannot import name poll

Tags: import, mininet, ryu

I am trying to launch https://github.com/OpenState-SDN/spider

when I try to Launch SPIDER:

```
$ cd ~/spider/src
$ sudo ryu-manager SPIDER_ctrl_WEBAPP.py
```

I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/bin/ryu-manager", line 9, in 
load_entry_point('ryu==3.29', 'console_scripts', 'ryu-manager')()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ryu/cmd/manager.py", line 88, in main
app_mgr.load_apps(app_lists)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ryu/base/app_manager.py", line 401, in load_apps
cls = self.load_app(app_cls_name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ryu/base/app_manager.py", line 378, in load_app
mod = utils.import_module(name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ryu/utils.py", line 91, in import_module
import(name)
File "/home/mininet/spider/src/SPIDER_ctrl_WEBAPP.py", line 25, in 
import SPIDER_ctrl
File "/home/mininet/spider/src/SPIDER_ctrl.py", line 30, in 
import SPIDER_parser
File "/home/mininet/spider/src/SPIDER_parser.py", line 33, in 
from mininet.topo import Topo
File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mininet/topo.py", line 14, in 
File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mininet/util.py", line 7, in
```

ImportError: cannot import name poll

Plesae, how to handle with this situation
thanks in advance

Comment: Whatever, I think my problem it is in these lines:

from mininet.topo import Topo
File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mininet/topo.py", line 14, in
File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mininet/util.py", line 7, in
ImportError: cannot import name poll

when I use SSh to get in (build/bdist.linux-x86_64), I didn't find anything inside.
So I think I must firstly add the missing files then I could solve my problem.

I do not know how I can do that
please, If you have any advice, it would be appreciated

I look forward to hearing you

Comment: Currently stuck in the same scenario, but nothing works! Tried to downgrade eventlet version `pip install -I eventlet==0.18.4`,
`pip install eventlet==0.18.4`, as per this page: https://www.cxyzjd.com/article/hangvane123/89960024, but it doesn't work!